# moving app over to a different server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to move an app over from an older server to another no so much older server. As far as I can tell the old app was (for some reason I did this) running on Unicorn, with ruby version 1.8.6. The new server supports 186 and 193 so it shouldnt be a problem. but I continuously get an error when i try to run the site.

http://omnimart.myitcrm.biz/

I have searched the web and couldnt find an exact post describing this error and a solution for it.

I tried to put 186 in nginx so that it would use the correct version of ruby, but I also get 193 showing up in the environment variables, and I figured that may be the problem, but I tried tracing these environment variables back to see where there were set and I couldnt find it anywhere. Could that be the problem?

nginx conf:

```
        server {

            passenger_ruby /home/purge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/wrappers/ruby;

            listen 80;
            server_name omnimart.myitcrm.biz;
            root /home/purge/www/omnimart/current/public;
            passenger_enabled on;

    }
```

The site is currently running now so it isn't an emergency but I would like to resolve this so i can shut down one node that only has one remaining app running on it.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this one?

Comment: 1.8.6 is beyond ancient and you really need to upgrade to a supported version of Ruby. Even 1.9.3 is cut off from support, it's hazardous to keep deployed. How big an app is this? Could you update to 2.0 syntax? Apart from UTF-8 issues in the 1.8 -> 1.9 switch it's usually not too bad.

Comment: Please copy the error messages into your post.

Comment: The Shellwords module changed between 1.8.6 and 1.8.7, replacing `escape` with `shellescape` if I'm not mistaken, so it seems like you *need* 1.8.6. The question is why you don't remove 1.9.3 from that machine if that's the case.

Comment: @MarsAtomic it is actually that 1.9.3 added `#escape` as an alias for `#shellescape`. `Shellwords#shellescape` was added in 1.8.7. OP can you please explain why you are using an rvm wrapper for 1.8.6 and using gems for 1.9.3. Your interpretter is "/home/purge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/wrappers/ruby" but your gems are "/home/purge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545:/home/purge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global" this appears to be your actual issue